# Call to insertSheet works in Google Script Editor and was authorised but dosent work when calling from the spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written a custom function that calls the code below to create a temporary sheet. When I ran it in Google Editor I was asked for authorisation and granted access.

My custom function runs well in Google Editor but doesnt work in the spreadsheet and I get the error "You do not have the permission to call insertSheet".

I created the spreadsheet and custom function so I own (have access) to everything.

```
  var tempSheetName = "temp";
  var sp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeCell = sp.getActiveCell();
  sp.insertSheet(tempSheetName);
```

Comment: How do you call it from within your spreadsheet?

Comment: I call it using my custom function name "=getSlopeSMA()" which contains the code to create the temporary sheet.

Answer (score 1):

From Google Apps Guide : [Link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

> If your custom function throws the error message You do not have
>   permission to call X service., the service requires user authorization
>   and thus cannot be used in a custom function.

Comment: I think the spreadsheet service is one that is allowed. The error relates to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You may have your reasons, why you want to accomplish it in this way. But I'm really not sure if a custom function in a cell is the right place to create a new tab. You usually do calculations within a cell not document manipulations.

What, if you'd create a menu entry for the function like this and call it from there?

```
function onOpen() {

  // instantiate UI object
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  // create the menu
  ui.createMenu("Functions")
  .addItem("Create Sheet", "createSheet")
  .addToUi();
}

function createSheet() {
  // get active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sheetName = 'mySheet',
      sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // delete sheet if it already exists
  if (sheet) ss.deleteSheet(sheet);

  // insert sheet
  ss.insertSheet(sheetName, 0);
}
```

Do you still get an error? Just curious...

Comment: He wants to use it with "Custom Function" like built function "=IF","=COUNT" ......, declare it inside cells

Comment: I use the sheet as temporary space where I put data and perform computation. I need to do it in a sheet since I cant access regular sheets functions (e.g. arrayfunction(), Googlefinance(),...) in Google apps script.

Comment: I can try again using your code and a menu. Does it work for you? It seems like your code is using insertSheet. My function returns a numeric value after the computation hence Id like it to be in a cell instead of menu but if that is the only way I might use the workaround.

Comment: Using custom functions in your scripts is not possible and creating tabs from custom functions is not possible. Then you should really give custom menus a try.